# Can't get flexbox to vertically justify elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm just starting to learn HTML/CSS and I can't get flexbox to vertically justify elements (or do much of anything at all). I'm having trouble conceptually understanding why it's not recognizing the elements as separate elements to justify.

CSS and HTML:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.odd-elements {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #687291;
  border-top-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dfe1e7;
}

.even-elements {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #687291;
  border-top-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eeeff2;
}

#e6 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #687291;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleA.css" />
  <title>CS142 Project #1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="odd-elements">A</span>
    <span class="even-elements">B</span>
    <span class="odd-elements">C</span>
    <span class="even-elements">D</span>
    <span class="odd-elements">E</span>
    <span id="e6">F</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're actually trying to achieve, however items with `display:block` are only as high as they need to be, unless you tell them otherwise. Give `.box` a `height` (or `min-height`) greater than the sum of the internal elements and you will see something.

Comment: can you please add screenshot of what you want. thanks

Comment: You must specify the extent of the `flexbox` along the *flex direction* (here it is *column*) so that it knows how much space it *can* occupy -  so give something like `height: 100vh` to see the vertical *justification*

Answer (score 0):

Just change your CSS to:

```
      .odd-elements, even-elements{
         display: inline-flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to center your child item, you have to use your child as a flex container. In that case, the span tags are your child. So, You have to add display: flex (To do flex container), justify-content: center, align-items: center in your span tag. By the way, It would be great If you add a common class in your span tag.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.odd-elements {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #687291;
  border-top-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dfe1e7;
}

.even-elements {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #687291;
  border-top-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eeeff2;
}

#e6 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #687291;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleA.css" />
  <title>CS142 Project #1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="odd-elements">A</span>
    <span class="even-elements">B</span>
    <span class="odd-elements">C</span>
    <span class="even-elements">D</span>
    <span class="odd-elements">E</span>
    <span id="e6">F</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```